# Tail recursive remove duplicate consecutive entries in list

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, tail-call

I'm attempting [problem 8 of the 99 OCaml problems](https://ocaml.org/problems#8), which asks you to write a function `compress` that removes consecutive duplicate entires in a list:

```ml
assert (
  compress
    [ "a"; "a"; "a"; "a"; "b"; "c"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "e"; "e"; "e"; "e" ]
  = [ "a"; "b"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "e" ])
```

I came to the following solution:

```ml
let head = function x :: _ -> Some x | [] -> None

let compress list =
  let rec fn old_list new_list =
    match (old_list, new_list) with
    | h :: t, _ ->
        fn t (if Some h = head new_list then new_list else h :: new_list)
    | _ -> new_list
  in
  List.rev (fn list [])
;;
```

The provided example solution by the website is as follows:

```ml
let rec compress = function
    | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
    | smaller -> smaller;;
```

At first, I thought that my solution was more efficient as it is tail recursive, while the provided solution is clearly not (requires us to keep the `a` in `a :: compress t` on the stack). However, when I test if my code is tail recursive:

```ml
assert (
  (compress [@tailcall])
    [ "a"; "a"; "a"; "a"; "b"; "c"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "e"; "e"; "e"; "e" ]
  = [ "a"; "b"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "e" ])
```

It gives me a warning saying it's not tail recursive. Why?

From my understanding, my solution doesn't require keeping any state on the stack, which should make it tail recursive.

**EDIT**
Also tried applying the `[@tailcall]` to `fn` directly via `List.rev ((fn [@tailcall]) list [])`, get the same warning.

Comment: see also [tag:tailrecursion-modulo-cons].

Answer (score 2):

When you make your assertion, `compress` isn't in tail position, `(=)` *is*. This has no bearing on your `compress` function implementation.

```
# assert (
  ((=) [@tailcall]) 
    (compress ["a"; "a"; "b"]) 
    ["a"; "b"]
);;
- : unit = ()
```

Similarly, in the expression `List.rev ((fn [@tailcall]) list [])`, the call of `fn` is not in the tail call position.

You can test this by trying:

```
let compress list =
  let rec fn old_list new_list =
    match (old_list, new_list) with
    | h :: t, _ ->
        (fn[@tailcall]) t (if Some h = head new_list then new_list else h :: new_list)
    | _ -> new_list
  in
  List.rev (fn list [])
```

Note also that tail-recursive does not always mean *more efficient*. Tail-recursive functions are often *less* efficient, but they can be used on large data without a stack overflow. If you are dealing with data likely to cause this, it suggests you may need to re-evaluate the data structure you're using.

We could also, as of OCaml 4.14 make `compress` tail-recursive with `tail_mod_cons`.

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec compress = 
  function
  | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> 
      if a = b then compress t 
      else a :: compress t
  | smaller -> smaller;;
```

Alternatively, you might implement this with continuation passing.

```
let compress lst =
  let rec aux k = function
    | ([] | [_]) as lst -> k lst
    | a::(b::_ as t) when a = b -> aux k t
    | a::t -> aux (fun i -> k (a :: i)) t
  in
  aux Fun.id lst
```

As yet another fun alternative that is tail-recursive, you might write a `compress` function which generates a [sequence](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html). In order to do this, our `aux` function needs to take an argument to keep track of the last value seen. Because at the beginning there will not be a last value seen, the `option` type makes sense.

```
# let compress lst =
    let rec aux lst last_seen () =
      match lst, last_seen with
      | [], _ -> Seq.Nil
      | x::xs, Some x' when x = x' -> aux xs last_seen ()
      | x::xs, _ -> Seq.Cons (x, aux xs (Some x)) 
    in
    aux lst None;;
val compress : 'a list -> 'a Seq.t = <fun>
# compress [1;1;1;3;3;4;6;6;7;4] 
  |> Seq.take 3 
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [1; 3; 4]
```

Of course, it may also be helpful to have this work directly on a sequence as the input, allowing it to work on other data types without first converting to a list. The translation is very straightforward.

```
# let compress_seq seq =
    let rec aux seq last_seen () =
      match seq (), last_seen with
      | Seq.Nil, _ -> Seq.Nil
      | Seq.Cons (x, xs), Some x' when x = x' -> aux xs last_seen ()
      | Seq.Cons (x, xs), _ -> Seq.Cons (x, aux xs (Some x)) 
    in
    aux seq None;;
val compress_seq : 'a Seq.t -> 'a Seq.t = <fun>
# [1;1;1;3;3;4;6;6;7;4] 
  |> List.to_seq
  |> compress_seq
  |> Seq.take 3
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [1; 3; 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured it out.

## 1) Is it tail recursive?

To test if the functions were tail recursive, I decided to just try and break them by inducing a stack overflow:

```ml
let _ = compress (List.init 10_000_000 (fun x -> Some x))
```

For my implementation, this works just fine. The provided solution, on the other hand, results in a segvault, which I'm assuming is from stack overflow:

```
[1]    70387 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

So we can conclude that my implementation is indeed tail recursive, while the other one is not.

## 2) Which one is faster?

I used the following to test the speed of both functions:

```
let _ =
  let l = List.init 250000 (fun x -> x) in
  let t = Sys.time () in
  let f = compress l in
  Printf.printf "Execution time: %fs\n" (Sys.time () -. t);
  f
```

Note, `250000` is the limit on my machine before things stack-overflowed.

For the tail recursive implementation, it was around `0.018s`.

For the non-tail recursive implementation, it was around `0.013s`.

So seems that the overhead of function calls is not enough to make the non-tail recursive implementation slower than the tail recursive one, which requires 2 passes of the list.

I should also be noted, this is also for the worst case, where our input list `List.init 250000 (fun x -> x)` is a list with all unique elements. The amount of stack space required for the non-tail recursive implementation is proportional to the number of **unique elements**, not the number of elements in the list, because in the left branch of `if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t`, we don't use any stack space. I tested this by changing the list to only hold a constant and made the list much larger `List.init 100000000 (fun x -> 0)`, and the non-tail recursive implementation no longer seg faults. It seems the OCaml compiler is smart enough to know that if the left branch of `if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t` is tail recursive, and only allocates a stack if the right branch is hit.

Comment: Yes, `if/else` is not a function call. In this case the true branch is tail-recursive, while the false branch is not because `::` in in the tail call position.

Comment: Also, you should be able to ascertain if your functions are tail-recursive by reading the source. Empirically testing them isn't necessary, but kudos for going to the effort.

Comment: Yeah, from reading the source, my initial hunch was correct, but I wanted to make sure it was correct since with more certainty, since I'm fairly new to functional programming.